# jQuery Validation - validate groups of checkboxes with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

I have two groups of checkboxes, all with the same name. E.g.

```
<div>
  <input class="category-group-1" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="a">
  <input class="category-group-1" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="b">
  <input class="category-group-1" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="c">
</div>

<div>
  <input class="category-group-2" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="x">
  <input class="category-group-2" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="y">
  <input class="category-group-2" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="z">
</div>
```

I need to require that at least one checkbox from each group be checked in order to pass validation. But as the validation plugin references fields by name rather than class or ID, I can't work out how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: please share your javascript

Comment: I don't have any javascript that's relevant to the question.  The javascript I've written so far doesn't contain anything that's relevant to the checkbox fields as I don't know how to do that bit, hence my question.

Comment: You can't do it with your current naming scheme.  **The jQuery Validate plugin mandates unique names**.  Example:  everything in the first grouping is named `category[1]` while the second grouping is named `category[2]`

Comment: @Sparky thanks, I feared that may be the case. Unfortunately, changing the naming scheme isn't an option. Ah well, at least I know to stop trying!

Answer (score -1):

Use the each function in jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    isChecked=false;

    $('.category-group-1').each(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            isChecked=true;
            return;
        }   
    })
    alert(isChecked);
}))
```

Comment: he wants at least one checkbox checked, not all

Comment: @oliv37. Oops. I misunderstood the problem. Fixed.

Comment: @Matt thanks, but the question relates specifically to the jQuery Validation plugin.